# Older question regarding Isaiah 7.14-16

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/813/in-light-of-isaiah-715-16-how-could-jesus-be-the-promised-child-born-of-a-virg) recently jumped to the top of the list. A *related* question could be something more like:

> Who are the young woman and the son from Isaiah 7.14 referring to?

But while the above example is *related* to the one that was actually asked, there does not seem to be a way to trim or edit the current question so that it does not reflect that specifically Christian perspective. The actual question asked *requires* a systematic Christian framework, so it seems it should be moved over to Christianity.SE.

(Still being relatively new to SE's features, I'm not aware if this is the appropriate place to make this suggestion.)

Comment: It's too late to migrate and the OP could have posted there himself.  Two options off the top of my head: 1. edit (or suggest one) and 2. vote to close.

Comment: I think closing would be the most appropriate option at this point. Editing the question to make it more neutral would destroy what was originally being asked.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've added my close vote.

Comment: I tried to answer this question strictly through the lens of the Hebrew Bible with no references to the Christian New Testament... please click [**here**](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/4484/921).